# getting wrong answer by logarithm in c++

Tags: c++, logarithm

Well i was creating a program in c++ .Then i noticed that there were some error due to which my program was not functioning correctly

**compiler used:- Dev c++**

Error was this:-

Suppose n1=274877906944 which is **2^38**. so log(n1) should be 38 which is correct. now let n2=274877906942 which is smaller than n1.

So that means if we calculate log(n2) then it must give me less than log(n1).But log(n2) gave me the same result as log(n1) which is 38.
Which is wrong!!!

Someone please explain this stuff..

Comment: If you you show us your code, we can help you better.

Comment: [`log2`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2) returns a `float` or `double` - so how are you getting an integer?

Comment: #include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
long double n;
cin>>n;
cout<<log(n)/log(2);
return 0;
}

Comment: The argument is cast to a double, and with floating point math being what it is, I think all those values are close enough to approximate an answer as "38"

Comment: Given the size of the values and the precision of floating point representation, the results look pretty good to me.  Have a look at an [online logarithm calculator](http://www.rapidtables.com/calc/math/Log_Calculator.htm) and compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see the result that you do because of rounding. If you increase your precision, it'll be okay (note that the `log2` function in `<cmath>` will cast your integers to `double`):

```
std::cout << std::fixed;
std::cout << std::setprecision(16);
std::cout << static_cast<double>(274877906944) << std::endl;
std::cout << static_cast<double>(274877906942) << std::endl;
std::cout << static_cast<double>(274877906948) << std::endl;

std::cout << log2(274877906944) << std::endl;
std::cout << log2(274877906942)  << std::endl;
std::cout<<  log2(274877906948) << std::endl;
```

Produces:

> 274877906944.0000000000000000 
>   274877906942.0000000000000000
>   274877906948.0000000000000000
>   38.0000000000000000
>   37.9999999999895053
>   38.0000000000209965

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/043f0f506de37f0e)

Comment: so i need to only type cast it into the double.That will do the job?                        or i just take the value in  double will it work?

Comment: `log2` is already returning a `double`. Store that result in a `double`, and to display it properly you'll need to increase the number of significant figures to be printed, as I've shown.